# Compile failed in VSCode for PlatformIO (Marlin) for 3D Printer TwoTrees Sapphire Plus

Tags: visual-studio-code, firmware, platformio, 3d-printing

I have installed VSCode v. 1.55.2 recently downloaded.
Installed PlatformIO plugin v. 2.3.2.
Installed Auto Build Marlin plugin v. 2.1.32

When I open a fresh downloaded Marlin FW v. 2.0.7, edit it
according to this guide on the bespoke changes needed for the Sapphire Plus printer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbHsNCDrTpY

and try to compile it for my MKS Robin Nano board (env: mks_robin_nano35) I get errors:

```
    Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
In file included from buildroot/share/PlatformIO/scripts/../../../../Marlin/src/inc/MarlinConfig.h:34:0,
                 from buildroot/share/PlatformIO/scripts/common-dependencies.h:31:
buildroot/share/PlatformIO/scripts/../../../../Marlin/src/inc/../pins/pins.h:525:12: fatal error: stm32f1/pins_MKS_ROBIN_NANO.h: No such file or directory
   #include "stm32f1/pins_MKS_ROBIN_NANO.h"      // STM32F1                                env:mks_robin_nano35
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CalledProcessError: Command 'arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -DTARGET_STM32F1 -D__MARLIN_FIRMWARE__ -DHAVE_SW_SERIAL -DMCU_STM32F103VE -DSS_TIMER=4 -D__MARLIN_DEPS__ -w -dM -E -x c++ buildroot/share/PlatformIO/scripts/common-dependencies.h' returned non-zero exit status 1.:
  File "C:\Users\skjor\.platformio\penv\Lib\site-packages\platformio\builder\main.py", line 175:
    env.SConscript(item, exports="env")
  File "C:\Users\skjor\.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.1.0\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 591:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\skjor\.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.1.0\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 280:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\skjor\OneDrive\Documents\IT\_3D_Printer\_TwoTrees Sapphire Plus\Firmware\Marlin-2.0.x_SapphirePlus_FromScratch_AutoAlignZ_FromVideoAuroraTech_ColorTouchscreen\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 286:
    apply_features_config()
  File "C:\Users\skjor\OneDrive\Documents\IT\_3D_Printer\_TwoTrees Sapphire Plus\Firmware\Marlin-2.0.x_SapphirePlus_FromScratch_AutoAlignZ_FromVideoAuroraTech_ColorTouchscreen\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 118:
    if not env.MarlinFeatureIsEnabled(feature):
  File "C:\Users\skjor\.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.1.0\SCons\Util.py", line 658:
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\skjor\OneDrive\Documents\IT\_3D_Printer\_TwoTrees Sapphire Plus\Firmware\Marlin-2.0.x_SapphirePlus_FromScratch_AutoAlignZ_FromVideoAuroraTech_ColorTouchscreen\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 262:
    load_marlin_features()
  File "C:\Users\skjor\OneDrive\Documents\IT\_3D_Printer\_TwoTrees Sapphire Plus\Firmware\Marlin-2.0.x_SapphirePlus_FromScratch_AutoAlignZ_FromVideoAuroraTech_ColorTouchscreen\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\common-dependencies.py", line 250:
    define_list = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).splitlines()
  File "C:\Users\skjor\.platformio\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 424:
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\skjor\.platformio\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 528:
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
```

Can anyone help. No help from the supplier TwoTrees.

Answer (score 0):

try it without the underscores and spaces, also maybe try shortening the location?

```
C:\Users\skjor\OneDrive\Documents\IT\_3D_Printer\_TwoTrees Sapphire Plus\Firmware\Marlin-2.0.x_SapphirePlus_FromScratch_AutoAlignZ_FromVideoAuroraTech_ColorTouchscreen\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts
```

to maybe

```
C:\MarlinFirmare\SapphirePlus\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts
```